# Does the equal sign reallocate memory in a char *?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

If i use the following code `char * foo = "words"`. Should i call `free()` before i do  : `foo = "two words";` . How does this assignemnt work? 
Is the memory containing the string "word" freed , then enough memory to hold the string "two words" then allocated and then foo set to point to the new string. I just want to make  sure my code is as efficient as possible and without any mem leaks .

Comment: If you call `malloc` (or if a function you call does), then you should call `free`.  If you don't call `malloc`, you ought not call `free`.

Comment: Make sure to read up on string literals and character buffers, and the different types of storage duration.

Comment: `char *foo` is just a pointer.  `foo` doesn't actually hold the string, and assignment to it doesn't allocate or deallocate anything -- it just changes what it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i use the following code `char * foo = "words"`. Should i call `free()` before i do  : `foo = "two words";` .

No. Argument to `free` must be a pointer previously returned by either `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` functions. Otherwise it will invoke **undefined behavior**.

> How does this assignment work?

When  compiler encounters a string literal of length `n`, it sets aside `n+1` bytes of memory for the string. A `char` pointer points to the first byte of allocated memory when the string literal is assigned to it.

Once stored in memory, string literals are available for the lifetime of the program.
If you assign `"two words"` latter to `foo`, then still `word` will continues to stored at that section, but this section is different from the location allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: ok , but what happens to the data that the char pointer was pointing to before? i.e. "word". Is it immediately popped of the stack?

Comment: @worlboss: I addressed that question in my answer.

Comment: @worlboss; String literals are available for lifetime of the program. See the update.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should only call `free` for an object that you have allocated through `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

`"words"` is an object with static storage duration and you cannot free the object.

Answer (score 2):

No need to call `free()`. In fact, it would fail. String constants declared like this are not on the heap and will exist for the life of your program regardless.

Call `free()` on memory that your program allocates using `malloc()`, etc.

Comment: It's not clear that `free()` would actually *fail*. The behavior would be undefined, which means it just might appear to "work". In fact the `free()` function has no way to tell you that it failed; it's your responsibility to call it correctly or not at all.

Comment: I guess I wasn't thinking of "appear to work" as actually working. No memory would be freed. To me, that is failure.

Comment: Why do you assert that no memory would be freed? It's entirely possible that an invalid call to `free()` *would* free some memory -- just not memory that had been properly allocated. The behavior is undefined; it could legally whistle Dixie.

Comment: `free()` manages a heap. If you pass it an address to memory not in the heap, then either A) it would recognize the memory is not in the heap and do nothing, or B) it would modify memory outside the heap. In neither case has any memory been *freed*.

Comment: Or C) it could behave in some completely arbitrary way, not limited to anything that makes any kind of sense. It could, for example, add the (non-heap) memory to a free list and make it available for future allocation. Since the behavior is undefined, talking about what it *doesn't do* really has no more foundation than talking about what it *does*.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I wouldn't call anything you've described as successfully freeing memory. I am calling that failure. You are welcome to call it something else. It's a semantic debate now.